# Angular4 selected option disappears after selection in "select" tag

Tags: javascript, angular, html-select, angular-forms

I have an issue in my Angular 4 application with a generated form, and more precisely, with a `<select>` tag where its `<option>` tags are dynamically generated.

I made a simplified version of my code in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/26miBUlNxpLtqKX5057t?p=preview).

The problem I'm experiencing occurs immediately after I select an option that's not the first default `undefined` option : the code value is set correctly but the text inside the `<option>` tag disappears.

How could I fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change [ngValue] in options to [value]

```
<select [(ngModel)]="value">
  <option [ngValue]="undefined">(undefined)</option>
  <option *ngFor="let entry of getEntries()" [value]="entry.code">{{entry.label}}</option>
</select>
```

This will work.

Comment: Quite simple solution that works fine, thanks ! But do you know what is the difference between `ngValue` and `value` ? Should I change the first `[ngValue]="undefined"` to `[value]="undefined"` too ?

Comment: [ngValue] will create the Angular binding for that element. However the [value] is simple attribute binding. And we should do the attribute binding only because we already have ngModel available to access its values.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `getEntries()` function you can directly use `entries` array in your `class App` like below code

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Please select one option : </p>
    <select [(ngModel)]="value">
      <option [ngValue]="undefined">(undefined)</option>
      <option *ngFor="let entry of entries" [ngValue]="entry.code">{{entry.label}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected value : {{value}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  value = undefined;
  entries=[{code:"1", label:"abra"},{code:"2", label:"kadabra"}];
  constructor() {
  }


}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>Please select one option : </p>
    <select (change) = 'myfun($event)'  [value] = 'this.value'>
      <option *ngFor="let entry of getEntries()"   [selected]= 'this.value'  (value)="entry.code"  >{{entry.label}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected value : {{value}}</p>
  `,
})
export class App {
   value:string

  constructor() {
  }

  myfun(event){
   console.log(event.target.value)
   this.value = event.target.value;
  }

  getEntries() {
    const entries = [];
    entries.push({code:"1", label:"abra"});
    entries.push({code:"2", label:"kadabra"});

    return entries;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```